# Creating a Basic Success Function for Http

Tags: ruby, http

I got sick of every time I make an Http request validating that the response was a success. I did a lot of:

```
if response.class == Net::HTTPOK
```

or

```
if response.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
```

I wanted something a little prettier so I came up with the following. I don't write a lot of class extensions like this so I wanted some input.

```
require 'net/http'
class Net::HTTPResponse
  def success?
    return false if ! self.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
    return true
  end
end
```

Now once the file is included I can say:

```
if response.success?
```

Comment: Just about every alternative to Net::HTTP has a better interface. Don't feel compelled to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your solution would work, I would have gone for something like this:

```
class Net::HTTPResponse
  def success?
    false
  end
end

class Net::HTTPSuccess
  def success?
    true
  end
end
```

If you do keep your solution, you could simplify it to:

```
class Net::HTTPResponse
  def success?
    self.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
  end
end
```

Comment: A short comment about what _like this_ or _could simplify it to_ mean would be great ;-)